# Read single text file and based on a particular value of a column load that record into its respective table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have been searching on the internet for a solution to my problem but I can not seem to find any info. I have a large single text file ( 10 million rows), I need to create an SSIS package to load these records into different tables based on the transaction group assigned to that record. That is Tx_grp1 would go into Tx_Grp1 table, Tx_Grp2 would go into Tx_Grp2 table and so forth. There are 37 different transaction groups in the single delimited text file, records are inserted into this file as to when they actually occurred (by time). Also, each transaction group has a different number of fields

Sample data file

> 1. date|tx_grp1|field1|field2|field3
> 2. date|tx_grp2|field1|field2|field3|field4
> 3. date|tx_grp10|field1|field2
>      .......

Any suggestion on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can be solved with SSIS, just with some experience. Here are the main steps and discussion:

1. Define a Flat file data source for your file, describing all columns. Possible problems here - different data types of fields based on `tx_group` value. If this is the case, I would declare all fields as strings long enough and later in the dataflow - convert its type.
2. Create a OLEDB Connection manager for the DB you will use to store the results.
3. Create a main dataflow where you will proceed the file, and add a *Flat File Source*.
4. Add a *Conditional Split* to the output of *Flat file source*, and define there as much filters and outputs as you have transaction groups.
5. For each transaction group data output - add *Data Conversion* for fields if necessary. Note - you cannot change data type of existing column, if you need to cast string to int - create a new column.
6. Add for each destination table an OLEDB Destination. Connect it to proper transaction group data flow, and map fields.

Basically, you are done. Test the package thoroughly on a test DB before using it on a production DB.

Comment: Thank you,  I'm giving that a try as we speak. It will be a difficult task as there largest row has 92 fields for a specific transaction group. And yes, the data type are not the same.